# gwtupload conflict with Activities and places framework

Tags: gwt, gwt-activities, gwtupload

I have a GWT application which has an upload feature, and it works fine with [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/)
However, it doesn't work after I setup Activities and places framework.
It gives the following submit error:

> Unable to auto submit the form, it seems your browser has security
> issues with this feature. Developer Info: If you are using jsupload
> and you do not need cross-domain, try a version compiled with the
> standard linker?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You link to google code but there is a version on github with multiple commits this year. Do you use the latest version?

https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload/commits/master

Comment: @thst - Thanks, I think, i use the latest version (1.0.3)